# Requests Library

Tags: python, html, web, screen-scraping

I am new to Python and its available libraries, and I am trying to make a script to scrape a website. I want to read all links on a parent page, and have my script parse out and read data from all children links from the parent page.

For some reason, I am getting this sequence of errors for my code:

```
python ./scrape.py
/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scrape.py", line 27, in <module>
    a = requests.get(url)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 494, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 305, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 379, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///?
```

From my Python script here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

#somesite = 'https://www.somesite.com/"

page = 'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/stop-limitorder.asp'

count = 0
#url = raw_input("Enter a website to extract the URL's from: ")
r = requests.get(page)              #requests html document
data = r.text                       #set data = to html text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")          #parse data with BS

#count = 0;
#souplist = []

#list
A = []

#loop to seach for all <a> tags that hold urls, store page data in array
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    #print(link.get('href'))
    url = link.get('href')
    print(url)

    a = requests.get(url)


    #a = requests.get(url)
    #data1 = a.text
    #souplist.insert(0, BeautifulSoup[data1])
    #++count



#
#for link in soup.find_all('p'):
    #print(link.getText())
```

Comment: step 1: do more work. If you get an error that suggests you are missing `http` or `https` in your URL, *print your URL to find out what you're actually passing in*, so do something like `print(url)` right before that requests.get(url)

Comment: your error is coming from `request.get(url)`. Look at the prints of your urls. they are NOT valid urls.

Comment: print(url) is giving me valid urls... this is one of them --https://plus.google.com/u/1/100137472973541677207/posts

Comment: it is not valid - there is no `http://` nor `https://` nor `ftp://` nor `file://`, etc.

Comment: @ElliotPressman so look at that URL, and look at your error: `Invalid URL '/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///?`, and we can see that Python is right: there is no schema. Where did the http or https etc go? (If you don't explicitly say which schema, or protocol, to use, Python has no idea whether you want a webpage, or an FTP site, or maybe even an IRC server feed, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the links the page your are scraping are relative URLs to the website(https://www.investopedia.com) . So you may have to crawl such URLs by adding the site.

```
from urlparse import urlparse, urljoin

# Python 3
# from urllib.parse import urlparse
# from urllib.parse import urljoin

site = urlparse(page).scheme + "://" + urlparse(page).netloc
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    #print(link.get('href'))
    url = link.get('href')        
    if not urlparse(url).scheme:
        url = urljoin(site, url)        
    print(url)
    a = requests.get(url)
```